# Have Rmarkdown knit to a custom markdown flavor?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

My workplace uses a custom flavor of markdown to generate its website and documentation. I am writing Rmarkdown reports and am having to knit to Github Flavored Markdown (closest flavor to our custom flavor) and then having to go in and manually change things to make it render correctly.

Are there resources, tools, or documentation that I could look at, to be able to write an output function similar to `github_document`? Is this possible in Rmarkdown? Specifically, is this possible for knitR or is this a pandoc question?

**EDIT:** To be more specific about the kind of changes I am manually making I would need to change embedded images from this:

```
![Figure Caption](path/to/image.png)
```

to

```
!media path/to/image.png
  id=image
  caption=Figure Caption
  style=width:50%
```

Where the style of the plot is taken from the metadata of the R-chunk.

Comment: From the bookdown documentation: [Creating New Formats](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/new-formats.html)